# how to prevent non-English characters and allow non-alpha characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string, and I want to make sure that every **letter** in it is English.
The other characters, I don't care.

1. `34556#%42%$23$%^*&sdfsfr` - valid
2. `34556#%42%$23$%^*&בלה בלה` - not valid

Can I do that with Linq? RegEx?

Thanks

Comment: So is "naïve" an English word for you?

Comment: @Joey - no, Only `a-z` or `A-Z`

Comment: @MitchWheat - I know only basic RegEx...

Comment: That's not evident from your question, as you haven't posted any RegEx.....

Answer (score 4):

You can define in a character class either all characters/character ranges/Unicode-properties/blocks you want to allow or you don't want to allow.

`[abc]` is a character class that allows a and b and c

`[^abc]` is a negated character class that matches everything but not a or b or c

Here in your case I would go this way, no need to define every character:

```
^[\P{L}A-Za-z]*$
```

Match from the start to the end of the string everything that is not a letter `[^\p{L}]` or `A-Za-z`.

`\p{L}` Is a Unicode property and matches everything that has the property letter. `\P{L}` is the negated version, everything that is not a letter.

**Test code:**

```
string[] StrInputNumber = { "34556#%42%$23$%^*&sdfsfr", "asdf!\"§$%&/()=?*+~#'", "34556#%42%$23$%^*&בלה בלה", "öäü!\"§$%&/()=?*+~#'" };
Regex ASCIILettersOnly = new Regex(@"^[\P{L}A-Za-z]*$");
foreach (String item in StrInputNumber) {

    if (ASCIILettersOnly.IsMatch(item)) {
        Console.WriteLine(item + " ==> Contains only ASCII letters");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(item + " ==> Contains non ASCII letters");

    }
}
```

Some more basic regex explanations: [What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)

Comment: `[^\p{L}]` is the same as `\P{L}`, by the way. You can then combine them into: `^[\P{L}A-Za-z]*$`

Comment: thanks for your simplification @Kobi, included it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use

```
using System.Linq;

...

static bool IsValid(string str)
{
  return str.All(c => c <= sbyte.MaxValue);
}
```

This considers all ASCII chars to be "valid" (even control characters). But punctuation and other special characters outside ASCII are not "valid". If `str` is `null`, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is put the char you want in this regx

```
bool IsValid(string input) {     
  return !(Regex.IsMatch(@"[^A-Za-z0-9'\.&@:?!()$#^]", input)); 
}
```

char other than specfied in the regx string are get ignored i.e return false..